# TypeScript giving error when using ChartDataLabels with Chartjs/react-chartjs-2

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I'm using React Chartjs 2 along with ChartDataLabels for a PieChart and it's been working great. I've recently upgraded the the versions below and I'm getting the following error:

`ChartDataLabels, htmlLegendPluginplugins={[ChartDataLabels]} ChartDataLabels, , htmlLegendPlugin │     Type 'Plugin<keyof ChartTypeRegistry, AnyObject>' is not assignable to type 'Plugin<"doughnut", AnyObject>'.  Types of property 'beforeTooltipDraw' are incompatible.`

I'm struggling to find out which package the library originates from, and I've checked all the GitHub issue trackers to see if anyone has had a similar experience but there's nothing obvious I can find.

The functionality seems to be working correctly but it would be nice to try and fix this error.

I'm using the versions below:

Chartjs: 4.3.0
react-chartjs-2: 5.2.0
chartjs-plugin-datalabels: 2.2.0

Comment: I have found the same issue. Have you solved it, in some way?

Comment: @asd I have same issue right now. Have you found any solution for this ?